# Excel2011 - Lookup and return multiple values into one cell BY DATE

Tags: excel, vba

I need to look up numbers (recurring) and return the value of the cells next to the number, but only for the same date. The results have to be joined into the same target cell.

I'm using Excel 2011 on a Mac. I don't have the Textjoin function. However, I located a VBA UDF to lookup and return multiple values into one cell. This is what I'm using:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

It kind of worked, but only for looking up the value in one cell and finding it in another column. The problem is that the value I'm looking up repeats on different dates, and I only want to return the values for a given date. I've attached a sample of what I'm trying to do below:

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLOo.png)

Notice the "Desired Data Format" G2 is returning the data for Employee 1001 for both dates in the database, but I only want it to return the data for the relevant date, so I tried to set first variable in the myvlookup UDF to "E2:F2" so that the function looks for both the Date and Employee#, but the function doesn't seem to work that way.

The values that should be displayed in G2 are  "80011, 80025", the values that should be displayed in G3 are "80011, 80030", etc.

I wish I had more time to figure this out on my own, but time is of the essence so I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a UDF that mimics the TEXTJOIN():

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

With your data you would use this in Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF((F2=B$2:B$14)*(A$2:A$14=E2),C$2:C$14,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.